# Android Studio button functionality not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am trying to learn android studio and I have made an app and in that app there is a screen which shows an image with buttons to move to previous/next images. Now the image is shown but the buttons don't work and my image doesn't change.

Following is the code for my java file

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
public class PhotoGalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private int[] imageIds = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5 };
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button previousButton;
    private Button nextButton;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery, container, false);

        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        previousButton = view.findViewById(R.id.previousButton);
        nextButton = view.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageIds[currentIndex]);

        previousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentIndex--;
                if (currentIndex < 0) {
                    currentIndex = imageIds.length - 1;
                }
                imageView.setImageResource(imageIds[currentIndex]);
            }
        });

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentIndex++;
                if (currentIndex >= imageIds.length) {
                    currentIndex = 0;
                }
                imageView.setImageResource(imageIds[currentIndex]);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

and following is the xml for that file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previousButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="Previous" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Following is the screen that I get and image doesn't change when clicking the buttons

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi you should remove `android:clickable="false"` or set `android:clickable="true"`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/previousButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="Previous" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Previous button attributes, you have set android:clickable="false”. Hence button is inactive. Set it to true and you are good to go.
Hope this should solve your problem.